# Typescript & nuxt : i18n types doesn't work

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

i am using **nuxtjs/i18n** in **typescript** and i've added its **types** in **TS config** :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@nuxtjs/i18n",
    ]
  }
}
```

**But** in componnets when i want to use

```
this.$i18n.locales
```

i have this **error**

[image]

[image]

**so , How can I fix types error for @nuxt/i18n ?**

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import { LocaleObject } from '@nuxtjs/i18n'
...
(this.$i18n.locales as LocaleObject[])
```